# rasa_nlu.model.UnsupportedModelError: The model version is to old to be loaded by this Rasa NLU instance

Tags: python, machine-learning, rasa-nlu

I'm building an chatbot using rasa. In the `train_online.py` file there are errors.

I moved to the latest version of rasa_nlu==0.15.1 but am still getting the error.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import logging

from rasa_core import utils, train
from rasa_core.training import online
from rasa_core.interpreter import NaturalLanguageInterpreter
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def train_agent(interpreter):
    return train.train_dialog_model(domain_file="horoscope_domain.yml",
                                      stories_file="data/stories.md",
                                      output_path="models/dialog",
                                      nlu_model_path=interpreter,
                                      endpoints="endpoints.yml",
                                      max_history=2,
                                      kwargs={"batch_size": 50,
                                              "epochs": 200,
                                              "max_training_samples": 300
                                              })
if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.configure_colored_logging(loglevel="DEBUG")
    nlu_model_path = "/home/zain/models/dialogue"
    interpreter = NaturalLanguageInterpreter.create(nlu_model_path)
    agent = train_agent(interpreter)
    online.serve_agent(agent)
```

This is the error

> "".format(model_version, rasa_nlu.**version**))
>   rasa_nlu.model.UnsupportedModelError: The model version is to old to
>   be loaded by this Rasa NLU instance. Either retrain the model, or run
>   withan older version. Model version: 0.0.0 Instance version: 0.15.0

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your RASA version was older than 0.15. You can resolve this by retraining the models by using command

```
python -m rasa_core.train -d domain.yml -s data/stories.md \
  -o models/current/dialogue -c config.yml
```

But i would suggest that you migrate to version 1.2.4 of RASA. There are many changes & makes easy for us to use RASA. I recently migrated from version 0.14.1 to 1.2.4 & it had benefited me a lot.

Still if you wish to use version 0.15 then use this [link](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/) for RASA docs. Else you can go for the recent RASA docs [here](https://rasa.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

This version problem can be solved by creating a virtual environment. All the packages will be installed inside your virtual environment and it will not conflict to the packages installed in your device.

Firstly, in the folder you want to keep your Rasa Bot, there open cmd and create virtual environment using `python -m venv --system-site-packages ./venv` 
then, activate virtual environment using `.\venv\Scripts\activate` and then use other commands as per your necessity.

Check Rasa's documentation about this: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/#create-a-virtual-environment-strongly-recommended

Hope this helps! ^_^